# App engine slow response time and optimization

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have a project on google app engine, and there are  several functions using the
Drive Java  API.

Also, i'm using the "com.google.appengine.api.users.User;"

when i'm using some function, for example: createDocument:

```
public FileResponse createDocument(FileRequest file, @Named("visibility") @Nullable String visibility, User user) throws IOException, OAuthRequestException,
        BadRequestException
{
    Utils.validateAuthenticatedUser(user);
    file.setValidator(new FileRequestValidator(FileRequestValidator.FileRequestType.CREATE));
    file.validate(file);
    Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(Globals.httpTransport, Globals.jsonFactory, Authenticator.credential(Constants.DRIVE_SCOPE, file.getDomainUser())).setApplicationName(
            "My - APP").build();

    File newFile = null;
    try
    {
        Drive.Files.Insert insert = drive.files().insert(file.getFile());
        if (visibility != null) insert.setVisibility(visibility);
        newFile = insert.execute();
        return new FileResponse(newFile);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.severe("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new OAuthRequestException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This function is working, but it takes over 920 ms. there is a way i can optimize it? even to pay more to google.

we can see that 700 ms of the time belongs the urlFetch

[we can see here the time of the response:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsPBY.png)

Comment: Does the creation of the document have to finish before the user receives a response? Typically, I delay the creation of the asset, giving the interactive user their http response first, creating the document in a task.

Comment: Thank you for the response. yes, our user is waiting till the document is ready and then, after he is getting a response, he can get in to the file.

Comment: Does the response to the user depend upon the contents of the created document? You can still create the document in an async task and give the caller a handle that will allow them to access the new document, provided the creation finishes before they attempt to access it. If the request comes before the creation is complete, the requestor can be delayed at that point, instead of during the initial call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats?csw=1) for profiling the Remote Procedure Call(RPC) performance of your application. RPC can make your application to work slow.

To keep your application fast, you need to know:

- Is your application making unnecessary RPC calls?
- Should it cache data instead of making repeated RPC calls to get the same data?
- Will your application perform better if multiple requests are executed in parallel rather than serially?

The Appstats verify your application if it is using RPC calls in the most efficient way by allowing you to profile your RPC calls. Appstats allows you to trace all RPC calls for a given request and reports on the time and cost of each call.